# How do I enable docker's experimental features so Gitlab can build with it

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

In a small swarm that has experimental features enabled and one that hosts gitlab-runners I seem to be unable to build with experimental features enabled. (I want to build with the --squash option)

`docker version` on the host shows `experimental: true`, but the same command in the gitlab-ci-runner shows `experimental: false`.

I can't seem to find any additional configuration options...

my runner config:

```
cat /srv/data/gitlab-runner/etc/config.toml 
concurrent = 4
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "bushbaby-general-ci"
  url = "xxx"
  token = "xxx"
  environment = ["COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR=/cache/composer", "COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1", "YARN_CACHE_FOLDER=/cache/yarn"]
  executor = "docker"
   [runners.docker]
     tls_verify = false
     image = "alpine:latest"
     privileged = true
     disable_cache = false
     volumes = ["/var/cache:/cache:rw"]
     shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out

ensure this is placed inside the .gitlab-ci.yml

```
some_build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:git

  services:
  - name: docker:dind
    command: ["--experimental"]
```

I presume the "privileged = true" in the runner config is also required but have not tested that